# Why does the JVM not detect missing method implementation?

Tags: java

We have an application where we publish and interface and an implementation separately. The users will compile against our interface, but only at run-time will they need to deploy the implementation. The implementation is never referred to explicitly.

I got a little curious about what happens if you mix versions of interface and implementation (where newer versions would have for example added methods). So, I made a simple example:

```
├── mix
│   └── Mix.java
├── v1
│   ├── DummyImpl.java
│   └── DummyInterface.java
└── v2
    ├── DummyImpl.java
    └── DummyInterface.java
```

v1 of the interface looks like this:

```
interface DummyInterface {
    void v1();
}
```

v2 of the interface looks like this:

```
interface DummyInterface {
    void v1();
    void v2();
}
```

The Mix.java file looks like this:

```
class Mix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DummyInterface di = new DummyImpl();
        di.v1();
        if (System.getProperty("foo") != null)
            di.v2();
    }
}
```

The *Impl classes contain some sort of implementation of the interfaces. What it does is not important.
The next step is a bit of trickery.

1. I compile the files in the v1 directory.
2. I copy the files from v2 to the mix directory so that I can compile the Mix.java
3. Running the program works, both with and without the property "foo" set.
4. I copy the DummyImpl.class from the v1 directory to the mix directory.
5. I run the program. It works.

The v1 implementation clearly does not fulfill the v2 interface, but the JVM will gladly allow me to run the program.

If I set the "foo" property it will fail, but not until I actually get to that line in the code.

I guess this is where my question comes: Is this guaranteed behavior? If so, where is it specified what will/should happen in this case?

My example is of course silly, but since we have a similar situations in a bigger system, I would like to know what we can count on to work, what wouldn't work and what we can't know if it'll work.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler generates an `invokeinterface` bytecode for your calls there (not `invokespecial`). This bytecode does a multistep-lookup for the concrete method to call at runtime. So your code does not fail at compile time.

Comment: Well, it does fail at compile time if I fail to implement all the methods. It just won't fail at application startup time if there are missing method implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Because you abstracted the interface, the client program doesn't know that the version running is v1.  When it tries calling a v2 method that doesn't exist in v1, you'll end up getting a (not-so) nice [`NoSuchMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html).

As a reminder, things marked as errors in Java are considered non-recoverable and you normally shouldn't try to catch it.